# custom message via html jquery validate not showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i learning jquery validation from >> http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/. I set custom message inline html, like this

```
<input name="pelatihan_performance" type="radio" value="1"  required />
<input name="pelatihan_performance" type="radio" value="2" />
<input name="pelatihan_performance" type="radio" value="3" />
<input name="pelatihan_performance" type="radio" value="4" />
 <input name="pelatihan_performance" type="radio" value="5" />

// error handler
<label for="pelatihan_performance" class="error">Harap pilih Kinerja</label>
```

but when i run this code, error just display "This field is required" not "Harap pilih Kinerja" . how to fix it ?

Comment: try `<input name="pelatihan_performance" type="radio" value="1"  required data-msg-required="Harap pilih Kinerja"/>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the custom message using a `data-msg-` property like

```
<input name="pelatihan_performance" type="radio" value="1"  required data-msg-required="Harap pilih Kinerja"/>
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ok7p0pcs/)

Still you want to place the error message in a particular place, you may want to override the `errorPlacement` option

Answer (score 0):

You can add custom message by rules

```
$('#form').validate({
    rules: {
        pelatihan_performance: {
            required : true
        }
    },
    messages: {
        pelatihan_performance: "Harap pilih kinerja"
    }
});
```